# Rails Way to Restrict Page Access Without Sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

**Context**

I'm building a super simple, knock-your-socks-off sexy sign-up page at http://hivechatter.com.  (Yes, I feel strongly about her.)

The root page is the new user action, where I ask for email only.  If the visitor submits a valid email, a new user is created and I redirect to that user's edit page and ask for additional, optional info.

**Problem**

The edit page url is of the usual form: http://hivechatter.com/users/19/edit.  One can visit any user's edit page by simply visiting this url with whichever id number they choose.

**Question**

How do I restrict access to the edit user page so that it can only be visited once, and only immediately after having created that user_id from the root new user page?

I can think of a variety of methods to explore.  I'd appreciate a pointer on the most elegant, rails way to do this.  Note that I don't need any additional functionality like sessions, etc.  This two step sign-up process is the extent of what I need right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add new column to your users table. Let it be `opened_once:boolean` with DEFAULT `false`

Then in your `users_controller`

```
def edit
  @user = User.find( params[:id], :conditions => ['opened_once => ?', false] ) rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @user.update_attribute :opened_once, true
  ...
end
```

so now it can be showed only once right after creating new user when you redirect to edit page

**UPD**

What you can do more Rails way? Without adding new stuff to your database and so on. You can remove your `edit` action at all, so your edit view will rendered at create:

```
def create
  @user = User.new params[:user]
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html{ render :action => :edit }
    else 
      format.html{ render :action => :new }
    end
  end
end
```

User will see edit form only once if validation passed and his profile created.

So this is specific `"Rails way"` :)

Comment: This is easy enough, though it feels like a hack.  I guess there is no "rails way" to handle this.  Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly the kind of solution I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The point of a cookie is to maintain state in the form of a session.  HTTP by spec is stateless,  and there for if you have people logging in then they need a session.  RoR has a great session handler,  I recommend using it.

The only other way to restrict access would be using a `.htaccess` file or similar method of doing `basic-auth`.  This doesn't scale well and is less secure.

Comment: The full version of that I'm working on does have sessions, cookie-based authentication, etc.  For the sign up page, I'm looking for a simple way to restrict access to the edit page, not full-fledged login functionality.

Comment: @Tim Koelkebeck to be honest I don't see how you can have any form of restriction/authentication without state.

Comment: Rook - Did you see the answer above?  He suggested adding a flag to the model.  It's a state, but it's simpler to implement than a cookie-based state.  Of course it's a bit of a hack, but since this is only a temporary sign-up page, the simplicity makes it the best option.